# Origin of "что-то/кто-то решает" construction

Tags: выражения, фраза

Here's the insignia of [the 339th Infantry Regiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/339th_Infantry_Regiment) of of the United States Army. For historical reason the motto is in Russian. The thing is that as for me the phrase "штык решает" sounds quite anachronic since I've been thinking that construction something + решает" (which can roughly be translated as that something rules) is sort of modern slang.

So the question is - when did this construction came into existence?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Собственно, всегда существовало и сейчас существует выражение "решить дело". Ну а поскольку слово "дело" употребимо и в военном контексте ("дело" = "бой"), то оно легко угадывается и даже может быть опущено, как в данном случае: *штык решает [дело]*.

UPD. Пожалуй, четко обосновать что глагол "решать" появился в (около)военном жаргоне прямиком из жаргона (около)юридического, будет затруднительно, хотя лично мне это кажется наиболее разумным объяснением. Но по меньшей мере в источниках XIX века найти подобное словоупотребление уже не трудно (в отличие от "цитат" из Суворова, которые вполне могут быть неаутентичными).

Например,

> "Штык и сабля решили бой."
>   "Наконец подоспел принц с шведами и россиянами 25-го числа и решил битву при Деневице."
>   [Глинка Ф. Н. "Письма русского офицера о Польше, Австрийских владениях, Пруссии и Франции, с подробным описанием Отечественной и заграничной войны с 1812 по 1814 год"](http://militera.lib.ru/db/glinka1/04.html)

Comment: "всегда существовало" это всё-таки крепкое выражение слишком) мне нравится гипотеза, что это часть выражения "решить дело" но не могли бы вы привести какие-то доказательства в пользу своей версии?

Comment: @shabunc Ну например, [Глинка Ф.Н. "Письма русского офицера..."](http://militera.lib.ru/db/glinka1/04.html): "Штык и сабля решили бой"; "".

Answer (score 2):

Привожу "доказательства", что выражение **"штык решает"** известно давно.

> Исход удачи, участь боя решает штык героя.(Пословица)

http://sbornik-mudrosti.ru/poslovicy-i-pogovorki-pro-shtyk/

> Петр Ершов Русский штык.(1833)
>
> Пушки бьются до последа,
>
> Штык кончает дело вмиг;
>
> Там удача, там победа,
>
> Где сверкает русский штык.

Ссылка .http://45parallel.net/anthology/petr_ershov/

> Небезынтересно привести здесь и еще более решительные афоризмы ген. Драгомирова и Сухотина в пользу штыка, которые также имели влияние на принятое в русской армии решение.
>   'Великое Суворовское начало - пуля - дура, штык - молодец останется вечно справедливым не потому, чтобы пуля была недействительна, но потому, что а) **штык решает дело**, б) он есть представитель воли, нравственной энергии, на которой зиждется все в боевом деле' (Драгомиров).